# Numpy. Compare all vector row in one array with every other one in the same array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array as below:

```
a= array([[2, 3],
   [0, 2]])
```

and want to compare "vectors" in each row with every other rows, using np.greater, so to have:

```
array([[False, False],  <--- [2,3] compared with [2,3]
     [True, True]],     <--- [2,3] compared with [0,2]
     [[False, False],   <--- [0,2] compared with [2,3] 
     [False, False]])   <--- [0,2] compared with [0,2]
```

But if I try `r=(np.greater.outer(a,a))` it compares every number in `a` with every other number in `a`, so to have:

```
array([[[[False, False],  <--- 2 compared with a
     [ True, False]],     

    [[ True, False],      <--- 3 compared with a
     [ True,  True]]],


   [[[False, False],      <--- 0 compared with a
     [False, False]],

    [[False, False],      <--- 2 compared with a 
     [ True, False]]]], dtype=bool)
```

¿How can I make an outer comparison row wise instead of element wise?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
a[:,np.newaxis] > a
```

It is the same as this more explicit code:

```
a[:,np.newaxis,:] > a[np.newaxis,:,:]
```

Hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500609/4323

Details on what it does: [The use of Python numpy.newaxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241056/the-use-of-python-numpy-newaxis)