# How to compare each row of vectors of numpy array to itself and every element

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array which contains vectorised data. I need to compare each of these vectors (a row in the array) euclidean distances to itself and every other row.

The vectors are of the form

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I know I need two loops, here is what I have so far

```
def euclidean_distance_loop(termdoc):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    matrix = np.array([])
    while( j < (len(termdoc-1))):
        matrix = np.append(matrix,[euclidean_distance(termdoc[i],termdoc[j])])
        j = j + 1
        
    return np.array([matrix])

euclidean_distance_loop(termdoc)
```

I know this is an index problem and I need another index or an incremented index in another loop but not sure how to construct it

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data and desired outcome? It'd be easier to understand the question

Comment: The data is a term by document matrix where each row is a vector. The function is to take each row and compare row[0] to itself and all other rows, then take row[1] compare to all rows and itself, row[2] and all other rows and itself. My problem is I don't know how to update an index for the outer and inner loop I think

Comment: Take a look at this wiki by Divakar: [https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method](https://github.com/droyed/eucl_dist/wiki/Main-Article#prospective-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need loops.

```py
def self_distance(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(x[:,np.newaxis] - x, axis=-1)
```

See also:

- [Numpy. Compare all vector row in one array with every other one in the same array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45263347/numpy-compare-all-vector-row-in-one-array-with-every-other-one-in-the-same-arra)
- [How can the Euclidean distance be calculated with NumPy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401712/how-can-the-euclidean-distance-be-calculated-with-numpy)